# Как обернуть каждую ссылку wp_list_categories в div?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть массив по выводу категорий в виде ссылок. Нужно каждую ссылку обернуть в div.

```
$children_category = array(
    'child_of'           => $category_id,
    'style'              => 'none',
    'orderby'            => 'slug',
    'hide_empty'         => 0,
    'exclude'            => '1',
    'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
    'hierarchical'       => 1,
    'title_li'           => '',
    'echo'               => 1,
    'depth'              => 0
   );
$fncat = wp_list_categories($children_category);
```

Comment: а как вы сами делали и что у вас не  получилось?

Comment: Пытался  через foreach сделать но это странным образом ломало скрипт и он становился опять списком а не ссылками.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте фильтр в `functions.php`.

```
add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', 'filter_list_categories', 10, 2 );
function filter_list_categories( $output, $args ){
    $output = str_replace('<a>', '</div><div><a>', $output);
    $count = 1;
    $output = str_replace('</div>', '', $output, $count);
    return $output;
}
```

Сначала перед каждой ссылкой добавляем открывающий и закрывающий div. Потом первый `</div>` убираем.

Comment: вы это серьёзно? элемент списка в див? семантика такая семантика :)

Comment: что спросили, то и ответил )

Comment: Вообще-то, конечно, вопрос надо править )))

Comment: В чем ошибка?)))

Comment: К сожалению не выходит через functions, слишком много подобных выводов летят на сайте, а их править уже не представляется.

Comment: Показалось, что html не допустит div внутри ul. Проверил - можно.

Comment: Дико извиняюсь но вы не правы, если вы присмотритесь у меня стоит:     'style  => 'none', что определяет вывод ссыклами а не списком

Comment: да, не заметил. исправлю ответ.

Comment: Исправил, попробуйте.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение через оператора str_replace

```
   $children_category = array(
        'child_of'           => $category_id,
        'style'              => 'none',
        'orderby'            => 'slug',
        'hide_empty'         => 0,
        'exclude'    => '1',
        'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
        'hierarchical'       => 1,
        'title_li'           => '',
        'echo'               => 0,
        'separator'          => '',
        'depth'              => 0
       );
     $fuckincat =  wp_list_categories($children_category);
     $fuckincat = str_replace('<a', '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 block-cat"><span> <a ', $fuckincat);
     $fuckincat = str_replace('</a>', '</a></span></div>', $fuckincat);
     echo $fuckincat;
```

Comment: Хорошо ж "нашел".. типа KAGG Design говорил не о том же. :)
Но html нужно учить, чтобы подобную ересь не рожать :)

Comment: @SeVlad, тут же без фильтров решение :) в предыдущем, кстати, регулярка не заработает по идее, т. к. ищется тег "<a>" без аргументов, а таких WP не генерирует

Comment: @alenkins, ну фильтр - это частность, Я про вообще - "найденное  решение" регулярками,

Answer (score 0):

Есть простое и хитрое, но капельку не идеальное решение. В шаблоне код с функцией заключаем в необходимые нам div.

Чтобы было: `<div><?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?></div>`

В качестве разделителя устанавливаем те же теги, но в обратном порядке:
`</div><div>`

Получим все ссылки, обёрнутые в теги, но это добавит в конец пустой `<div></div>`

Не идеально с точки зрения чистоты кода, но зато на 100% решается задача очень простым способом. Визуально этот маленький косяк тоже никак не отразится.